# Kotlin cast String value to the correct representation

Tags: kotlin

I have a method that accepts a `value: String?`. The purpose of the method is to convert the String value to the correct representation. For example:

`"true" -> a Boolean that has a true value`

`"20" -> an Int that contains 20`

`"1223.2" -> a Dobule`

What is the most effective/concise way to achieve this result in Koltin?

**UPDATE**

Here is my current code:

```
private fun insertRealType(map: WritableMap, key: String, value: String?) {

    val test = getValueType(value)

    when (test) {
        is String -> map.putString(key, test)
        is Boolean -> map.putBoolean(key, test)
        is Int -> map.putInt(key, test)
        is Double -> map.putDouble(key, test)
        else -> map.putNull(key)
    }
}

private fun getValueType(value: String?): Any {

    var returnValue: Any?

    returnValue = value?.toDoubleOrNull()

    if (returnValue != null)
        return returnValue

    returnValue = value?.toIntOrNull()

    if (returnValue != null)
        return returnValue

    // ETC......
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like so far? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @zsmb13 Here is a sample code snippet I've been working on

Answer (score 1):

This solely depends on your interpretation of what is the "correct" representation. For instance, a value of `"0"` could be an `Int` or a false `Boolean`.

Another issue you'll face here is that you'll have to dynamically cast the variable either way. If you chose to create a `JSONObject` out of that string and generate a `List<Object>` from it, or even if you wrote your own method that converts string values to `Object`s, you'll still need to cast said object to its appropriate form (possibly check its type using the `is` operator). In order for you to have a method this abstract, you'll have to deal with casting its generic result manually.

I can help you out with a more practical answer than a conceptual one like this, but you'll need to provide some code

Comment: Correct. But, ya i do know that "1" and "0" is not a boolean for me. Also, i have posted a code snippet that I've worked on as a sample

Comment: I understand that by convention, most people can agree on a string literal's type. I was simply just illustrating some pitfalls.
I checked your snippet and I have to ask, what's wrong with it? Your code's logic is on the right track so far! Just keep checking for the other types you're supporting in `getValueType()`

Comment: I am relatively new to Kotlin, so i thought maybe there are extensions/shortcuts that i am not familiar with yet.

Comment: @TareKKhoury - It's possible that there is something buried in the Kotlin stdlib somewhere, but this requirement is quite specific.  If this corresponds to (say) JSON conversion, then you may be better off using a dedicated JSON library (e.g. Jackson).

Comment: I agree with @OliverCharlesworth regarding using a dedicated JSON library if the conversions correspond to what you're seeking. I can also tell you for sure that, coming from a Java background, this kind of type-inference has to be done manually. I'm almost entirely sure that's the case with Kotlin as well. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314215/java-how-to-infer-type-from-data-coming-from-multiple-sources) out, it's pretty much what you've done!